# android studio 3 : Error:(26, 105) error: illegal character: '\ufeff'

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I was trying to do this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3f0NAn5xFy4&list=PLS1QulWo1RIbb1cYyzZpLFCKvdYV_yJ-E&index=14)

But there's an error then try to do with the top comment seen at below

Why do I still got an error `Error:(26, 105) error: illegal character: '\ufeff'`

Here is my code

```
package com.pete.mseuf.intent;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private static Button Button_Submit;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OnClickButtonListener();
 }

 public void OnClickButtonListener(){
    Button_Submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button_Submit.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , 
                                    Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
 }
}
```

Added my xml file from AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pete.mseuf.intent">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.pete.mseuf.intent.Main2Activity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my Layout xml activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.pete.mseuf.intent.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am new here at stackoverflow and in android studio. Thankyou for your patience

Comment: Do you convert your project or create a new project in android studio?

Comment: Can you share your layout xml file?

Comment: @EnamulHaque I have added the xml's

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities :you have miss typed the character '\ufeff' in your XML

Answer (score 0):

Open `build.gradle (Module: app)` form `Gradle Scripts` section in your android studio project

Add this line

```
compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'
```

inside `android {//add line hare}` like this

```
android {

   compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'
}
```

clean the project and run..
I hope it will solve your problem...
feel free to ask..